# PHP PDO Access Issue

Tags: php, pdo

I currently have a database call which works in one area, but not another.

My database class is labeled $database and has the `$db` PDO object passed to the database constructor.

This all works fine.

This code call works

```
$user_info = $database->get_user($user);
```

This function is called

```
public function get_user($user){
        $user = $this->db->quote($user);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login where username = $user";
        $user = $this->db->query($query);
        $user_info = $user->fetch();
        return $user_info;}
```

This returns the user info as expected

Another call is

```
        $user = $database->confirm($confirm);
        $user_info = $database->get_user($user);
```

The confirm function looks like this

```
        public function confirm($confirm){
        $confirm = $this->db->quote($confirm);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM temp_data WHERE hash = $confirm;";
        $count = $this->db->query($query);
        $info = $count->fetch();

        $user = $info['username'];
        $user = $this->db->quote($user);
        $query = "DELETE FROM temp_data WHERE username = $user;";
        $this->db->exec($query);
        $query = "UPDATE login SET confirm = '1' WHERE  username = $user;";
        $this->db->exec($query);
        return $info['username'];}
```

This call works perfectly.

It returns the username in an unquoted format which the `get_user` accepts

However the `get_user` fails

I have done troubleshooting and found the issue is that the following line in `get_user` is not returning any PDO object, or any data at all

```
$user = $this->db->query($query);
```

This is the interesting part. I did a try catch and the PDO is throwing no PDO exception and it is not even throwing a general exception. There are no errors in the error log. It just appears not to be working. I have went through step by step using `Print_r`, `get_class`, and  `echo` followed by a `die;` to output my results and it all works up until I do the second database call. The fetch is returning an error, but that is only due to the fact the exec is not running at all it seems

I did try using `unset()` on everything but my main DB connection that is created and passed into my database object when it is created

Here is what is happening when the script is run

1. The user clicks on a link with a random hash
2. The system gets the hash from the GET and then uses that too pull the user name from the temp database.
3. It then modifies the user as confirmed, deletes the temp entry and then returns the user name
4. from here it then calls the `get_user`. In this case it just returns the user information to set up the twilio sub account. This is where the system is failing
5. After that what happens (And this it does try to do from my testing because i get an error here) is that it accesses the twilio API, gets a sub acount AUTH and SID token and writes it to the users file
6. Then the new user is redirected to the signin page

I have tried using close cursor and it has not worked.

If anyone can give me any insight into the issue I am having, or what I am doing wrong I would appreciate it. I am new to using the PDO object so I am sure I have made a stupid mistake somewhere.

Comment: I haven't got the answer for your problem. But why aren't you using the `bindParam()` method to bind value with escaping to the sql?

Comment: What does the `$info` contain? Maybe this array is empty. With as a result the second query being fed with the `username` being `''`

Comment: Confirm works fine the issue is with get_user so $info retruns the correct information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the answer from a great guy at the PHPFreaks IRC channel.

```
public function get_user($user){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM login where username = :u');
        $stmt->bindValue(':u', $user);
        $stmt->execute();

        $user_info = $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        return $user_info;
}


public function confirm($confirm){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM temp_data WHERE hash = :h');
        $stmt->bindValue(':h', $confirm);
        $stmt->execute();
        $info = $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM temp_data WHERE username = :u');
        $stmt->bindValue(':u', $info['username']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE login SET confirm = '1' WHERE  username = :u');
        $stmt->bindValue(':u', $info['username']);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $info['username'];
}
```